# UEFI prevents installing linux

Tags: linux, uefi

Being Belgian, all laptops come with windowsTM pre-installed.  Ingnorantly, I bought on thinking I would be able to install (K)ubuntu.  I found out the UEFI is just microsoft's way to prevent you doing this.  It stops you booting from USB or CD, it does not allow installing Linux or anything.

I tried the F2/F10 options and settings, I disengaged the security options, disabled secure boot, changed boot order, I tried changing HD with compatible laptop and running OS, tried to bang it against my head, nothing lets me install Linux, it just says:"no bootable device found"

Comment: This is not a programming question, so off topic, try super users

Comment: 1) you can disable secureboot 2) there's [shim](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide/sect-UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide-Implementation_of_UEFI_Secure_Boot-Shim.html) or the Linux Foundation's [pre-bootloader](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/news-media/blogs/browse/2012/10/linux-foundation-uefi-secure-boot-system-open-source) which are signed by Microsoft and allows you to boot with  SecureBoot enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UEFI dual booting Linux and Windows is big tangled mess. I've pulled it off with Ubuntu and Fedora, but after a lot of effort. There are a lot of important variables here. I'm more likely to be able to offer a solution with the following info:

- Which media are you using – USB or optical?
- How did you create the media? (e.g. Pendrive, Rawwrite, etc.)
- Which laptop manufacturer? (This is surprisingly relevant)

Also, it will help us all in the long run if we get more insight into the specific UEFIs and start documenting this issue more thoroughly. UEFIs are embedded software typically written by third-party companies like Insyde. You can find yours by installing a Windows system detailer like Speccy or HWInfo64. See the attached screenshot from Speccy. This info is unlikely to help here and now, but it will help us long-term: I'm looking to create a repository for these UEFI boot issues if someone hasn't done so already. [image: UEFI info from Speccy]

Comment: - I am using USB to boot - have extracted an iso image to the usb - it's a packard bell

Comment: Have you found or created this UEFI boot issue repo?

Comment: In general, you can't just copy an iso image to a USB stick and have it work as a Linux install disk on a Windows 8.x PC. The USB install image needs to be written by a special tool, like Pendrive. See these instructions: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-kubuntu-10-04-on-a-flash-drive-using-windows/

and here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

LinuxLiveUSB looks interesting too, and they have an issues page: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/faq/boot/54-my-usb-device-does-not-boot

Comment: Also, be sure you're using a bootable USB port. On some laptops, not every USB port is bootable. Typically, the USB 3.0 ports can't be used for this purpose – installing a Linux live USB on a Windows 8.x machine. It has to be a USB 2.0 port, and sometimes, it's only one of the ports that is bootable on any given machine. This is the case on my Sony VAIO. I have two USB 2.0 ports, but only one of them seems to boot.

Comment: @hewi I haven't created the UEFI knowledge base yet (or found one.) It's sorely needed.

Also, the USB 3.0 ports – the ones to be avoided here – are the ones with the blue plastic inside, sometimes with a lightning bolt symbol above the port. I apologize if this is too obvious for you.

Comment: LearningFast: No, I indeed used "USB Installer" from Ubuntu

Comment: I used USB port 2.0, as the installer usb port; don't apologize for giving basic info, always usefull

Comment: What's the status on this? Did you get it working? I'm not sure the USB Installer from Ubuntu is known to work. You might have to use one of the dedicated third-party USB creators like PenDrive.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Fedora 22.  There is a UEFI trampoline to get passed this hurdle.  If I had a UEFI machine I'd have tested this answer; it is theoretical at best.